# ActionName HttpPut not found

Tags: http-post

I have a weird problem. I have 2 Actions in controller:

```
[ActionName("Tag")]
    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult TagPut(Entities.Tag tag)
    {
        if (tag.Name.Length < 2)
        {
            throw new Exception("Minimalna dlugosc tagu 2 znaki");
        }

        database.TagRepository.Update(tag);

        return Json(tag, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and

```
[ActionName("Tag")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TagPost(Entities.Tag tag)
    {
        if (tag.Name.Length < 2)
        {
            throw new Exception("Minimalna dlugosc tagu 2 znaki");
        }

        database.TagRepository.Insert(tag);

        return Json(tag, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I call in JS action http://localhost:51991/AdminTag/Tag with optional tag id (http://localhost:51991/AdminTag/Tag/1) when I edit existing item. Action TagPost works well and I can Insert new Tag into Database, but action TagPut return error 404. Why application can't found Action with the same name as Action which work well?

Comment: I get absolutely the same problem!! Did you find out anything?